# Why am I obtaining this error trying to set a JSON field with a value? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'today_avg_price' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am not so into JavaScript and I am going crazy trying to perform this script that, starting from a JSON document creates another JSON document:

(I put my example into an html file and debugged it on Chrome, you can do the same to test it):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Before the script...</p>

  <script>
    function checkForNull(value) {
        if (value instanceof Object && "@nil" in value) {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }

    console.log("START")

    var payload = JSON.parse(`
        {
            "Markets": {
                "Market": {
                    "market_name": "Tambacounda Market N1",
                    "market_description": "Tambacounda Market N1",
                    "localization_id": 2,
                    "long": 13.776796,
                    "lat": -13.672198,
                    "country": "Senegal",
                    "regione": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "province": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "district": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "town": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "village": {
                        "@nil": "true"
                    },
                    "commodity": {
                        "el": [{
                                "commodity_details_id": 4,
                                "commodity_name_en": "Red onion",
                                "commodity_name": "Red onion",
                                "image_link": "Red_onion.jpg",
                                "today_avg_price": 20.1500,
                                "yesterday_avg_price": 33.3300,
                                "currency": "XOF",
                                "measure_unit": "kilogram",
                                "price_series_id": 1
                            }, {
                                "commodity_details_id": 6,
                                "commodity_name_en": "Green Beans",
                                "commodity_name": "Green Beans",
                                "image_link": "Green_Beans.jpg",
                                "today_avg_price": {
                                    "@nil": "true"
                                },
                                "yesterday_avg_price": 778.0000,
                                "currency": "RWF",
                                "measure_unit": "kilogram",
                                "price_series_id": 17
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `);

    // create new response          
    var response = payload.Markets.Market;
    console.log("RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify(response));

    // convert null values
    response.regione = checkForNull(response.regione);
    response.province = checkForNull(response.province);
    response.city = checkForNull(response.city);
    response.district = checkForNull(response.district);
    response.town = checkForNull(response.town);
    response.village = checkForNull(response.village);

    // convert array of commodities into required HATEOS format
    var commodity = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < response.commodity.el.length; ++i) {
        var el = response.commodity.el[i];  
        var newEl = new Object();
        newEl.commodity_name = el.commodity_name;
        newEl.commodity.today_avg_price = el.today_avg_price;
        newEl.commodity.yesterday_avg_price = el.yesterday_avg_price;
        newEl.rel = "commodity_details";
        newEl.href = "http://5.249.148.180:8280/commodity_details/" + el.commodity_details_id;
        newEl.type = "GET";

        commodity.push(newEl);
    }

    response.commodity = commodity;


    console.log("END");
  </script>

  <p>...After the script.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the original document is into the **payload** object.

The problem occur on this line of the first iteration in the for cycle:

```
newEl.commodity.today_avg_price = el.today_avg_price;
```

and give this error message:

```
parse_json_market.html:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'today_avg_price' of undefined
at parse_json_market.html:97
```

As you can see this JSON fields contains the **20.1500** value

```
"today_avg_price": 20.1500,
```

Why? What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just add this code before `newEl.commodity.today_avg_price`

```
newEl.commodity = new Object();
```

The reason is because `newEl` is `object` but `newEl.commodity` is `undefined`.
so you have to set `newEl.commodity` as object before calling `newEl.commodity.today_avg_price`.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0npymywz/)

Answer (score 1):

As `commodity` object is not present in newly created  `newEl` object.
That's why it's giving error `commodity` is undefined right now and can not set property on an undefined.

So, all you have to do is create and empty object like `newEl.commodity = {}`
before setting any property in it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `newEl.commodity_name = el.commodity_name;` works as you created an object on the previous line.

But you have not created a commodity object.  E.g. something like...

```
var newEl = new Object();
newEl.commodity_name = el.commodity_name;

var commodityObj = new Object();
commodityObj.today_avg_price = el.today_avg_price;

newEl.commodity = commodityObj;
```